# Is info saved in Titanium.App.Properties secure?

Tags: security, encryption, properties

I am using Titanium.App.Properties to save user login (username and password) for user to login next time the app is started without typing the login credentials.

My question, is this the best way to do this and whether data saved in Titanium.App.Properties is encrypted and not accessible by any external app.

Answer (score 0):

i think u can using Titanium Backup Root. cause This exhaustive app can save almost anything: apps, application data, messages, system settings, widgets, backgrounds, you name it.

Comment: Looks like this is irrelevant. My question is about securely saving user credentials within the app, using Titanium (Appcelerator) capability. I am unsure how Titanium backup root comes into play here? As per Android and iOS, there are ways to securely keep certain user information. I am checking to see if TitaniumApp.Properties is the best way to manage this.